# OpenID Connect: Resource Owner Password Credentials

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

OIDC doesn't support Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant. Why? Some of my clients are secured devices which could safely maintain credentials... Those credentials could be used to get an access_token. Can I still use OpenID Connect?

Answer (score 6):

It is not explicit in the specification but OpenID Connect supports all OAuth 2.0 flows since it is an extension of OAuth 2.0.

The spec talks about the flows that involve browser redirect as they are more common, more secure and less brittle given that resource owner credentials only supports username and password and is only in the OAuth 2 spec for backwards compatibility. In true SSO systems you'd want to abstract away from the method of authenticating the user at the OP/IDP. Involving a browser is a way to do that.

But your mileage may vary wrt. support in specific OP/AS software and client libraries.

FWIW: you should be looking to obtain an id_token rather than an access_token.

Comment: Thank you! "In true SSO systems you'd want to abstract away from the method of authenticating the user at the OP/IDP". Could you please elaborate on this? I would like to use SSO even for my secure devices... Do I miss the point?

Comment: what you typically do not want is to extend your client with all possible authentication mechanisms that the Identity Provider can use; imagine for example the introduction of second factor authentication: your client should have to care about implementing that, just leave it up to the browser

Answer (score 1):

> OpenID Connect performs authentication to log in the End-User or to
>   determine that the End-User is already logged in. OpenID Connect
>   returns the result of the Authentication performed by the Server to
>   the Client in a secure manner so that the Client can rely on it.

With implicit and authorization codes grant types flows, it is not possible to issue an ID token if the End-User is not logged in. In this case, the authorization server can confirm to the relying party that End-User is logged in. 
But with the resource owner grant type flow, the authorization server cannot confirm the End-User is logged in. You can issue an access token even if the End-User is not logged in.

Comment: This answer confuses things: the authentication of the user is always performed by the Authorization Server, even/also in the Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC) flow. The difference is in the fact that in ROPC the client "sees" the username/password of the Resource Owner unlike the other flows, which defeats the primary purpose of a federated SSO protocol like OpenID Connect where authentication mechanisms and credentials should be independent from the client/app. For that reason you won't see much use of ROPC in OpenID Connect, with an exception perhaps in intra-enterprise use cases.

Comment: -1 Your quote does not explain in any way why the ROPC flow could not be used in OIDC. Like @HansZ. said, the Authorization Server still does the authentication in a ROPC flow.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I updated my answer as it was not really clear.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  I also was finding answer for same question sometimes back.  According to the OpenId Connect specification, It is recommended to use `authorization code` and `implicit` grant types for OpenId Connect requests. But it is not mentioned that other grant types can not be used. Therefore you can use any other grant types for OpenId Connect authentication request.  There is some mail from the openid connect group,  which has been discussed on this.  Please find it from [here](http://lists.openid.net/pipermail/openid-specs-ab/Week-of-Mon-20130128/002981.html). If your OAuth2 Authorization server supports it, I guess that it is fine to use it.  As i know, most of the Authorization servers support it,  as an example from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/03/09/openid-connect-support-with-resource-owner-password-grant-type/)